# Problems when debugging a socket-using program in C: connect

Tags: c, debugging, sockets, kdbg

I'm writting a simple client-server system using unix sockets. When executed from a terminal, my Client program creats a segmentation fault.

I'm quite sure that seg-fault is caused by some noob error, but my problem comes when I try to debug it using KDBG  (kde gdb frontend).

This is where it breaks:

```
 if (DEBUG) printf("-- connect()... \n");
 if (connect (mySocket, (struct sockaddr *)socketAddr,sizeof (*socketAddr)) == -1) {
  perror(error);
  printf("%s\n",error);
  printf ("-- Error when stablishing a connection\n");
  return -1;
 }
```

And this is the output:

```
-- connect()... 
Connection refused

-- Error when stablishing a connection
```

Can't I debug this code that way? Why?

If I should can, do you now what's hapenning there? What should i do in order to get more information?

PS:
PS: @abelenky: that part works perfect out of the debugger. This is the declaration of socketAddr:

```
struct sockaddr_in socketAddr; 

... 

if ( (mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    printf("Error al crear el socket\n"); 
    return -2; 
}
```

Comment: stablishing?   Is that a form of "establishing"?

Comment: You should describe how you've created the socketAddr structure, and provide evidence that you have an accessible server to connect to (ie, without firewalls or routing causing problems)

Comment: @abelensky - Yo por mi parte supongo que "jesusiniesta" es un hablante nativo del español, asi que cuando tu consigas escribir en su idioma al nivel que ha escrito en el tuyo, que sigas quejando ...  :P

Comment: @asveikau @abelensky : Yes, I am not an english native speaker. In fact i'm really bad at it. But it's ok to know when I make a mistake and try to improve my english.

Answer (score 0):

These functions expect a string and you are passing them something else.

For example:

```
perror("socket");
```

Although I don't know from your code where `error` is declared...   Perhaps you are thinking of the global variable `errno`, which is in integer?

By the way, [`perror`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/perror/) is roughly equivalent to this:

```
void perror(const char *str)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", str, strerror(errno));
}
```

**Update based on comments:**

In that case my guess is you haven't intiailized `error` to anything...  I am not sure what you are expecting to be in `error`, but for example you might want to try something:

```
snprintf(error, sizeof(error), "Error in %s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
perror(error);
```

**Update 2:**

I think you want this:

```
if (connect (mySocket, (struct sockaddr *)&socketAddr, sizeof (socketAddr)) == -1) {
```

Note that I have added a `&` before `socketAddr` and removed the `*` from the `sizeof`.

How are you doing hostname lookups?  I recommend [`getaddrinfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo), eg.:

```
struct addrinfo *res = NULL, hint;
char service[32];
int error;

snprintf(service, sizeof(service), "%d", port);

memset(&hint, 0, sizeof(hint));
hint.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

if ((error = getaddrinfo(host, service, &hint, &res)))
{
   fprintf(stderr, "No se pudo encontrar %s: %s\n", host, gai_strerror(error));
}
else
{
   fd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
   if (fd < 0)
   {
      perror("Error al crear el socket");
   }
   else if (connect(fd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen))
   {
      perror("Error al conexionar con el servidor");
      close(fd);
      fd = -1;
   }
}

if (res)
{
   freeaddrinfo(res);
}
```

This will let you get a `sockaddr` from a hostname and port without caring about IPv4, IPv6, etc.

Comment: Now i get: Error in socket.c:96: Connection refused. Is that errno 96? It means "Protocol family not supported"... but I don't now how to take that.

Comment: @jesusiniesta 96 is the line number of your file...  I don't know what kind of message you want to put in there, but I was just trying to give an example and explain the unprintable characters.

Comment: As for why you get the "Connection refused" error...  There is no server listening on the other end.  Can you show where `socketAddr` came from?

Comment: oops, how noob was that? Thanks for the input, i didn't understand the  right use of perror. I have put the declaration of socketAddr in the first post. It works out of the debugger.